# Use of '<style scoped>' in Nuxt.js (SPA)

Tags: css, routes, single-page-application, nuxt.js

I start the project with nuxt.js / express.

We have developed style scoped for each component (.vue) in nuxt.js. So, when routing , the property is overlaid on the same class name (style), so the page does not display properly.

**1. What is the correct use of 'style scoped'?**

**2. Or should the routing process be `<a>` rather than `<nuxt-link>`?**

Answer (score 6):

> 1. What is the correct use of 'style scoped'?

The  [`<style scoped></style>`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles) notation is not ambiguous, as the `scoped` attribute suggests, all the CSS elements defined within this scope apply only to the current component. If the CSS element exists globally, the scoped one -having the same name and type- takes precedence, that is, it overrides the globally defined CSS element.

For example, let us define in /components folder 3 components Component1.vue, Component2.vue, Component3.vue:

**Component1.vue**:

```
<template>                                                                                                                                             
  <div class="yellow-text">Component 1</div>                                                                                                           
</template>                                                                                                                                            

<script>                                                                                                                                               
export default {                                                                                                                                       
  name: 'Component1'                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                      
</script>  
<style>
.yellow-text {
  color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

**Component2.vue:**

```
<template>                                                                                                                                             
  <div class="yellow-text">Component 2</div>                                                                                                           
</template>                                                                                                                                            

<script>                                                                                                                                               
export default {                                                                                                                                       
  name: 'Component2'                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                      
</script>  
<style scoped>
.yellow-text {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

**Component3.vue:**

```
<template>                                                                                                                                             
  <div class="yellow-text">Component 3</div>                                                                                                           
</template>                                                                                                                                            

<script>                                                                                                                                               
export default {                                                                                                                                       
  name: 'Component3'                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                      
</script>
```

- In Component1.vue, the text will be displayed in yellow.
- In Component2.vue, the text will be displayed in red because the scoped CSS class takes precedence over the globally defined one in Component1.vue.
- In Component3.vue, the text will be displayed in yellow.

So to respond to your question: there is no correct way because there is only one way to do that, and the meaning is not subject to any form of interpretation.

> 2. Or should the routing process be  rather than ?

Even if `<nuxt-link />` is rendered as `<a href>`, the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/) clearly states the former must be used to navigated through the Nuxt.js application and *In the future, we will add features to the  component, like pre-fetching on the background for improving the responsiveness of Nuxt.js Applications.*