# NuxtJS wrong css load order

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a problem with loading CSS to Nuxt app. There is a wrong order of loaded CSS rules. Here is an example:

// component.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="my-component">
    ...
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.my-component {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

// page.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="my-page">
        <my-component class="my-page__component" />
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.my-page__component {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

// build.css

```
.my-page__component {
    background-color: blue;
}
.my-component {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red; /* winning rule (wrong) */
}
```

The priority of inner styles of component is higher than outer what is wrong (and works fine in SPAs but not Nuxt). Do you have any idea how to fix this, I thing - common - problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592158/use-of-style-scoped-in-nuxt-js-spa

Comment: @Phix: not related